# After form submission, getting square brackets on GET variable

Tags: wordpress, forms, variables, get

i send variables to the referring site, after my form submission in Wordpress. My form contains a checkbox field where the field name is "service". On submission i get square brackets to the field name and then its not working. Why do i get these square brackets? This is the url:

[https://www.my-site.com/project/?&service[]=Webdesign&service[]=Logodesign](https://www.my-site.com/project/?&service%5B%5D=Webdesign&service%5B%5D=Logodesign)